# Will AUTO_INCREMENT id be unique for a table with Partitions in MariaDb?

Tags: sql, mariadb, database-partitioning

I've a use case where I want to create partitions on table and that table has AUTO_INCREMENT field. Let's say I've defined Partition Strategy while creating table. For example if a table `my_table` with field `id` as `AUTO_INCREMENT` and has 4 partitions `p0_my_table, p1_my_table, p2_my_table, p3_my_table`.

Now my question is Will `id` be unique across all partitions OR will `id` be unique within each partition.

Answer (score 0):

> Will AUTO_INCREMENT id be unique for a table with Partitions in MariaDb?

Yes, it will be unique across partititions.